# -post-build not a dependency for -do-debug but is for release

Tags: android, ant, adt

Regarding Android's "parent" build file. Location: `android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml`.

**I was just wondering why `-post-build` is not a dependency for `-do-debug` and it is for `release`.**

I would like to copy the APK that was generated by the build script to a specific location, and `-post-build` seems like the best place to do that. However, it is not called in `-do-debug`. It also seems like it would be the only place to do such a thing. Because for `release`, `-post-build` is called after all of the signing.

Am i missing something here? Is there a better way to acheive that? Or is this just a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** definitely a SDK bug! - had a co-worker run into it just now using **r15** of the Android SDK.

I'm using Android SDK r17, running the debug ant task **does** cause the **-post-build** task that I defined in my build.xml to run.

Perhaps this was a bug in the SDK version you are using.

I have [a blog post with an example](http://maks-tilt.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/automatic-android-release-builds-with.html) of how I am using the **-post-build** task.